# Issue with JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am having problems with the following code:

```
public void detachTab(TabComponent tc) {
    Logger.add("Detaching Tab");
    for (int i = 0; i < globalTabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
        if (tc == globalTabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(i)) {
            Logger.add("Detaching panel: " + i);
            SeparateWindow sw = new SeparateWindow((JPanel) globalTabbedPane.getComponentAt(i));
            sw.setVisible(true);

            globalTabbedPane.remove(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It simply removes a tab from a JTabbedPane and places it in a separate window. Pretty self explanitory. The issue is that the method also removes the tab below it.  I dont see how this is possible. Maybe there is something im overlooking.

Comment: Try removing the component before you add it somewhere else and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, but...

```
SeparateWindow sw = new SeparateWindow((JPanel) globalTabbedPane.getComponentAt(i))
```

Is likely adding the `Component` to the window, removing it from the `JTabbedPane`, the tabbedpane may be then be removing the associated tab, now meaning that the index positions have changed, so when you call

```
globalTabbedPane.remove(i);
```

you are now removing the following tab...

You could try getting a reference to the component, removing it and the creating the window...

```
JPanel pane = (JPanel) globalTabbedPane.getComponentAt(i); 
globalTabbedPane.remove(i);
SeparateWindow sw = new SeparateWindow(pane);
```

Comment: You are correct. For some reason the SeparateWindow line removes the tab. Removing the explicit call fixes the error.

Comment: When you add a component to another container, it is first removed from it's existing parent...